# Why does this code produce an empty dictionary and how can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to read a file and split on multiple characters. If I put the log statement within the rl.on block I get some outputs but for some reason the dictionary is empty again when the block is done.

```js
let rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: fs.createReadStream('Spanish.txt'),
    })
```

```js
   let dict={};
   let arr1=[];
   let arr2=[];
   rl.on(`line`, (line)=>{
       if (!line.startsWith('#')){
           arr1=line.split('\t');
           if (arr1[1]!=undefined) {
               arr2 = arr1[1].split('[').join(',').split('/').
               join(',').split('(').join(',').split(',');
               dict[arr1[0]]=arr2[0];
           }
       }
    });
    console.log(dict);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines are read asynchronously, so by the time you log your `dict`, processing has not yet completed.

You can listen for the [`close`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_event_close) event to determine whether the file has been fully read:

```
rl.on('close', () => console.log(dict));
```

Better yet, use an `async`/`await`-based approach as detailed in the [Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_example_read_file_stream_line_by_line).